# How to generate association rules with quantity in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

Now I am trying to solve a problem of generating items relevance with quantity using association rules in PySpark environment.

The raw data is like this:

```
----------------------------
trans   item_code   item_qty
----------------------------
001         A          2
001         B          3
002         A          4
002         B          6
002         C          10
003         D          1
----------------------------
```

My aim is to predict the probable additional items for given items. For example, given {A:2,B:3} the probable new set maybe {A:2,B:3,C:5}. So my first step is to generate association rules with quantity coefficient. My method is to use FP-growth algorithm to generate frequent item sets and then find one to one association rules. After filtering the rules by confidence threshold, I can calculate the quantity coefficient. My desired association rules DataFrame is like this (item1->item2):

```
----------------------------  
item1  item2  conf   coef 
----------------------------
  A      B     0.8    1.5
  B      A     1.0    0.67
  A      C     0.7    2.5
----------------------------
```

My spark version is 1.5.1. My code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pyspark import SparkContext,HiveContext
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
import time

#read raw data from database    
def read_data():
    sql="""select t.orderno_nosplit, 
          t.prod_code, 
          t.item_code, 
          sum(t.item_qty) 
          as item_qty 
          from ioc_fdm.fdm_dwr_ioc_fcs_pk_spu_item_f_chain t
          group by t.prod_code, t.orderno_nosplit,t.item_code """
    data=sql_context.sql(sql)                  
    return data.cache()

#calculate quantity coefficient of two items 
def qty_coef(item1,item2):    
    sql =""" select t1.item, t1.qty from table t1
           where t1.trans in 
           (select t2.trans from spu_table t2 where t2.item ='%s'
           and
           (select t3.trans from spu_table t3 where t3.item = '%s' """ %  (item1,item2)
    df=sql_context.sql(sql)
    qty_item1=df.filter(df.item_code==item1).agg({"item_qty":"sum"}).first()[0]
    qty_item2=df.filter(df.item_code==item2).agg({"item_qty":"sum"}).first()[0]
    coef=float(qty_item2)/qty_item1
    return coef

def train(prod):

    spu=total_spu.filter(total_spu.prod_code == prod)
    print 'data length',spu.count(),time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    supp=0.1  
    conf=0.7
    sql_context.registerDataFrameAsTable(spu,'spu_table')
    sql_context.cacheTable('spu_table')
    print 'table register over', time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    trans_sets=spu.rdd.repartition(32).map(lambda x:(x[0],x[2])).groupByKey().mapvalues(list).values().cache()
    print 'trans group over',time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    model=FPGrowth.train(trans_sets,supp,10)
    print 'model train over',time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    model_f1=model.freqItemsets().filter(lambda x: len(x[0]==1))
    model_f2=model.freqItemsets().filter(lambda x: len(x[0]==2))

    #register model_f1 as dictionary
    model_f1_tuple=model_f1.map(lambda (U,V):(tuple(U)[0],V))
    model_f1Map=model_f1_tuple.collectAsMap()

    #convert model_f1Map to broadcast
    bc_model=sc.broadcast(model_f1Map)

    #generate association rules
    model_f2_conf=model_f2.map(lambda x:(x[0][0],x[0][1],float(x[1])/bc_model.value[x[0][0]],float(x[1]/bc_model.value[x[0][1]])))
    print 'conf calculation over',time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    model_f2_conf_flt=model_f2_conf.flatMap(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))

    #filter the association rules by confidence threshold
    model_f2_conf_flt_ftr=model_f2_conf_flt.filter(lambda x: x[2]>=conf)

    #calculate the quantity coefficient for the filtered association rules
    #since we cannot use nested sql operations in rdd, I have to collect the rules to list first
    asso_list=model_f2_conf_flt_ftr.map(lambda x: list(x)).collect()
    print 'coef calculation over',time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    for row in asso_list:
        row.append(qty_coef(row[0],row[1]))

    #rewrite the list to dataframe
    asso_df=sql_context.createDataFrame(asso_list,['item1','item2','conf','coef'])
    sql_context.clearCache()
    path = "hdfs:/user/hive/wilber/%s"%(prod)
    asso_df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext()
    sql_context=HiveContext(sc)
    prod_list=sc.textFile('hdfs:/user/hive/wilber/prod_list').collect()  
    total_spu=read_data()
    print 'spu read over',time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    for prod in list(prod_list):
        print 'prod',prod
        train(prod)
```

The code can work, but it works really slow. I know that maybe it is mainly because of the step of calculating the quantity coefficient at the end part. But I don't know whether there is more efficient use of Spark(1.5.1) methods to achieve the result. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate association rules with quantity more efficiently in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318295/how-to-generate-association-rules-with-quantity-more-efficiently-in-pyspark)

Comment: @user9613318 Yes,that's my post, too. But it has not been answered. I really hope someone can give me some idea on this problem.

Comment: I understand you hope to get an answer, but posting the same question all over again, is not OK, and won't get you closer to getting one. Once you have enough rep, you can post a bounty to increase visibility,  but it might be better, to just provide _minimal_ and _reproducible_ example (both qualifiers equally important). Just glancing over the code you have, you collect without any good reason - first thing to target.

Comment: @user9613318 Thank you! Maybe it is because the descriptions of my previous posts are not clear nor simple. I have simplify the description and make it focused on  the key problem.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523055/why-my-simple-spark-application-works-so-slow. Hope it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

What if you paste the items?

```
--------------
trans   item
--------------
001       A2   
001       B3   
002       A4   
002       B6    
002       C10  
003       D1    
---------------
```

And then to transactions

```
trans   item
-------------
001     A2,B3
002     A4,B6,C10
003     D1
```

Then run association