# Why my simple Spark application works so slow?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to `count` the frequent item sets generated by FP growth of mllib using Spark API. My Spark is version 1.5.1. The following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark import HiveContext
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']='/usr/bin/python'
appName = "FP_growth"
sc = SparkContext()
sql_context = HiveContext(sc)

def read_spu(prod):#prod_code):
    sql = """
        select 
        t.orderno_nosplit, 
        t.prod_code, 
        t.item_code, 
        sum(t.item_qty) as item_qty
        from ioc_fdm.fdm_dwr_ioc_fcs_pk_spu_item_f_chain t
        where t.prod_code='%s'
        group by t.prod_code, t.orderno_nosplit, t.item_code  """%prod
    spu_result = sql_context.sql(sql)
    return spu_result.cache()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spu=read_spu('6727780')  
    conf=0.7             
    trans=spu.rdd.repartition(100).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[2])).groupByKey().mapValues(list).values().cache()
    model = FPGrowth.train(trans, 0.01, 100) 
    freq_count = model.freqItemsets().count()
    print 'freq_count:',freq_count  
    sc.stop()
```

The input data are read from Hadoop, and the data is not very large, only about 20000 rows. However, the script works very very slow in the stage of `.count`. I don't know why. From the performance, it seems it is because of data skew. But the output data is not large(only about 100KB per task ).

The cluster has 8 nodes of 320 cores and 1.56 T total memory (not only one user). My spark-submit script is `spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 30g --num-executors 20 --executor-cores 5 FP_growth.py`

**The attachments are the screen prints of performance when running:**

[Resource used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtnAO.png)

[Active Stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHbWu.png)

[Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKtdC.png)

Comment: Inefficient when the map is this simple: `rdd.repartition(100).map(lambda x: (x[0],x[2])).groupByKey()`


Improvement:  
`rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[2])).groupByKey().repartition(100)`

Repartition **after** groupByKey(), this transformation can be very expensive

Comment: @AssHat_ Thank you. I will revise this part. But the performance indicate the it is the `.count `stage that takes the longest time (hours).

Comment: .count is the **action**, it includes performing ALL of the transformations  (none of them occur before .count is used)

Comment: @AssHat_ Thank you. Yes, I understand that. But it is weird that the `count` in my script takes too long time ( **hours** ) for such small amount of data size.

Comment: The point is...you have to look at everything that is occurring when you use .count. Try placing .collects, etc after each transformation and see if you can narrow it down is my advice

Comment: @AssHat_  Now it puzzles me that if none of the transformations occur  before `.count` stage, the transformation stages won't take time, but the  timestamps indicate those transformation stages take some time, though very short (e.g. 0.3s )

Comment: Looking at tasks screenshot, appears that model.freqItemsets() is taking long time to run on some partitions? Within the count **stage** this is performed prior to the count (previously I was speaking at the count **job** level)

Comment: A number of the tasks completed quickly (0.3s), and others very slowly (after 20 min still incomplete). Does the number of **slow tasks** remain constant between executions?

Do some **prod_code** have more associated **item_code** than others (large variation)?

Comment: @AssHat_  Thank you very much. Your answer makes me have a better understanding of Spark. Actually, the data size is not so large. Sometimes even when the prod_code has only several thousands rows of data, it can still be extremely slow. Now I find out what makes it slow is that the value of `support` I set is too small. It is a matter of the FP-growth algorithm.  I can't imagine the value of this argument could have such huge influence on the running speed.